# How To Define Applicaiton Level Array in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have created one megamenu in layout file. megamenu will be display on whole applicaion.
that megamenu will be dynemic fillup.

so now my problem is that can i specified array at one location and access in all view .... irespective of controller and action.

Array are come from database.

Comment: Create static method in model for menu which returns your array, then just use whenever you need: `MyModel::getMegaArray()`

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to create a widget http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.view#widget and put your all menu stuffs there.

So if your menu is on every page, Your widget should be in a views/layouts file (views/layouts/main.php)